# Salesforce1 and Chatter

Tags: chatter, salesforce1-app

I use the sales force 1 app and when I log a call after an appt it shows up on Chatter. I will copy and paste what I see on chatter below and then once a week I get a weekly recap of my chatter which lists thee calls. I log call activity from the PC all the time and it only shows under the opportunity or contact. Can you help me figure out what I'm doing wrong. I would like to log call notes after I leave the customer but would prefer them NOT to be broadcast to all on Chatter.

Answer (score 2):

The Salesforce1 app uses the Log a Call publisher action. As of this writing, all Create a Record and Log a Call publisher actions create a Chatter feed item when Chatter is enabled for the organization.

At the moment there isn't a way to configure the action so it doesn't produce a feed item. It's on the Actions team's roadmap for a future release (safe harbor).